# lynda training not working with latest angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are currently going through the Angular training videos from Lynda, however, we are on chapter 3, and already experiencing issues. 
After hours debugging, it turns out to be the version of angular.

we have this as app.js

```
angular.module('airline', [])
.config(airlineRouter);

function airlineRouter ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/destinations.html',
     controller: function  ($scope) {
        $scope.setActive('destinations');
     }})
    .when('/flights', {template: '<h3>Flights</h3>',
     controller: function  ($scope) {
        $scope.setActive('flights');
     }})
    .when('/reservations', {template: '<h3>Your Reservations</h3>',
     controller: function  ($scope) {
        $scope.setActive('reservations');
     }});
}
```

the demo used  AngularJS v1.0.7 which works as should,  however, 
upgrading to  AngularJS v1.2.14 and it doesn't work. nothing happens on the page.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3):

As of Angular 1.2 the `ngRoute` module was [split out into a separate file](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/11/angularjs-120-timely-delivery.html). You'll need to include that on the page along with AngularJS itself.

Note that this means you'll also need to import the module into yours:

```
var yourModule = angular.module("yourModule", [
    "ngRoute"
]);
```

See the [latest docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) for more details.

Comment: At the risk of sounding silly, but where do you download ngRoute.js?

Comment: @Simon - Read the latest docs I linked to. It has download links. Here's one on the [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#angularjs).

Comment: I've looked at that, which just points me back to the angular home page?

Comment: The "latest docs" link in my answer sends you to the home page? Weird, working for me! Anyway, use this and make sure `X.Y.Z` matches the version of Angular you are using: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js`

Comment: hi, I have tried this now, and have both the angular-route and angular included (in the correct order), and unfortunately, this lynda sample will still will not work.

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes from 1.0 to 1.2, and one that may impact this piece of code can be seen below.

**ngRoute has been moved into its own module**: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngroute-has-been-moved-into-its-own-module